# Use column names from dataframe and create a new one with one column with those column names as values

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below and I want to create a new one with 2 columns one named `Amenities` which will include either "nn_bank" or "nn_hospital" as value and the other column "Name" with the name of the `nn_bank` or `nn_hospital`.

```
df<-structure(list(state = c("West Bengal", "West Bengal", "West Bengal", 
"West Bengal", "West Bengal"), nn_hospital = c("Khundkuri Hospital", 
"Khundkuri Hospital", "Mankar Rural Hospital", "Khundkuri Hospital", 
"Khundkuri Hospital"), distance_nn_hospital = c(8949.68646563084, 
17217.1419457099, 16939.2318150416, 15812.9872649418, 1408.372117616
), nn_bank = c("contai", "contai", "Allahabad Bank", "contai", 
"contai"), distance_nn_bank = c(13959.9950089655, 20598.4763042432, 
19688.6296071566, 20537.3799009137, 11385.8738290783)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
5L))
```

result should be like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple value columns one option would be to use the `names_pattern` argument of `tidyr::pivot_longer` along with the special `.value` to reshape your data. Afterwards you have to do some additional cleaning.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(stringr)

df |>
  pivot_longer(-state,
    names_to = c(".value", "Amenities"),
    names_pattern = "(.*?nn)_(.*)"
  ) |>
  select(-c(state, distance_nn), Name = nn) |>
  mutate(across(c(Amenities, Name), str_to_title))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    Amenities Name                 
#>    <chr>     <chr>                
#>  1 Hospital  Khundkuri Hospital   
#>  2 Bank      Contai               
#>  3 Hospital  Khundkuri Hospital   
#>  4 Bank      Contai               
#>  5 Hospital  Mankar Rural Hospital
#>  6 Bank      Allahabad Bank       
#>  7 Hospital  Khundkuri Hospital   
#>  8 Bank      Contai               
#>  9 Hospital  Khundkuri Hospital   
#> 10 Bank      Contai
```

Comment: tnx that is based on your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76457839/combine-values-from-2-dataframes-to-calculate-average-for-new-column

Comment: Hej firmo, I dropped the `distance` and state columns. To achieve your desired result drop the `select()` and use `rename(Name = nn, Distance = distance_nn, State = state)` instead. And to add your average columns use `mutate(State_Avg = mean(Distance), .by = c(State, Amenities, Name))`